# Velocity charts in Rally

Tags: rally

In Rally, what is the difference between the [iteration velocity chart](http://www.rallydev.com/help/progress-reports#velocity) and the [enhanced velocity chart](http://www.rallydev.com/help/enhanced-velocity-chart)?

It looks to me that the dark green and light green bars are the same in both, and that the iteration velocity's red bar is the same as the enhanced velocity's clear.  Is this true?

What are the differences between these two charts - i.e. why are there two different charts for seemingly the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like one is a report, and another is an app you can place on your dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, although the iteration velocity chart is a report, you can also add it as a dashboard app, just as you can add the enhanced velocity chart to your dashboard as an app. So what is the purpose of the enhanced velocity chart if the iteration velocity chart can be added to the dashboard in the same way?

Comment: Dunno.  I think you might have to contact Rally about that.

Comment: The best way to get an answer to this question is to contact Rally Support.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly related to programming.